# Margin left for form using Bootstrap 2.3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am failing to see how can I align a form with the beginning of an image using Bootstrap 2.3.2.

Here is my code:

```
<body>

  <div class="container">
      <img src="http://s10.postimg.org/6xjbbn6yh/0_Bl8if_L2_Et_AUQg_Y_n0_dsw.png">
    <div class="form">
        <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/orders/97" class="form-horizontal" data-remote="true" id="edit_ad_586" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="patch"></div>
          <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="score">Score</label>
            <div class="controls">
              <select class="input-small" id="ad_score" name="ad[score]"><option selected="selected" value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="10">10</option></select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
              <input class="btn btn-primary" name="commit" type="submit" value="Score!">
            </div>
          </div>
</form>      </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

And here is live: [Bootstrap left margin in form](http://jsfiddle.net/BVmUL/205/)

I would like the form to avoid having that left margin and be aligned with the beginning of the picture.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to simply overwrite the CSS, use the following:

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/KxLkw/)

```
.form-horizontal .controls {
    margin-left: 0px;
}
.form-horizontal .control-label {
    width: 54px;
    text-align:left;
}
```

This removes the `margin-left` on `.form-horizontal .controls`, and then reduces the width of `.control-label` and aligns it to the left rather than the right.

I don't use bootstrap, therefore I don't know the most efficient way to achieve this. Nonetheless, this seems to be what you want.